# ApplicationDidEnterBackground and UIWebview

Tags: uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I have a issue with an application.
I'm building an application that is somekind of webApp.
So the application runs on a server and i interact with it trought a UIWebview.

So let me explain what i'm trying to achieve here.
On the webpage i have several Javascript functions, i interact with these functions trought the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
example:
Code:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"tagMe()"];
```

and the server executes this command and does the following

it sets the URLPrefix to ServerReply://() and i catch this with

```
- (BOOL)webViewUIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequestNSURLRequest *)request navigationTypeUIWebViewNavigationType)navigation Type
```

so if the URL has a Prefix ServerReply:// it runs a function in my app.

So far so good everything works just fine, BUT when the user pushes the HOME button or he gets a phonecall. the ApplicationDidEnterBackground method will be called and i want to call another JS function

Code:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"gettingClosed()"];
```

and then the server should give me an URL with Prefix SaveClientData://(somestring)

So the app closes and it doesn't work ....
my code is something like this

Code:

```
//AppDelegate.m

  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [webViewController killTrigger];
 }

//webViewController. m

-(void)killTrigger{

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"gettingClosed()"];

}
```

and this doesn't work but if i do
Code:

```
  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [webViewController killTrigger];
 }

//webViewController. m

-(void)killTrigger{

NSLog(@"killTrigger got called");

}
```

i get the log message when i leave the app ...

is it possible to do [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"gettingCl osed()"]; if my app moves to the background ? or is there a different approach to get the same result ... ?

tnx in advance,

Bart

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I still wanted to post a solution. I had a similar problem: I wanted to close a websocket when my application enters the background, but it seemed iOS suspended the thread before this could go through. The solution to this was registering a background task:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground
{
    self.cleanupBackgroundTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.cleanupBackgroundTaskIdentifier];
        self.cleanupBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    [self.remoteWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"websocket.close();"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(cleanupBackgroundTaskTimeout) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
}

- (void)cleanupBackgroundTaskTimeout
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.cleanupBackgroundTaskIdentifier];
}
```

This tells iOS that we want to continue working in the background and then closes the websocket. We then give the websocket enough time to close (10 seconds in this case) and end the background task after that.

Please note that the block you pass to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` is **not** the code that is executed in the background, the call to this method just tells iOS that your app should not be suspended immediatly.

Also, be aware that there is no guarantee you will get extra time for background work and that you MUST call `endBackgroundTask:` in time (usually 10 minutes) or iOS will kill your application.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario and have some strange behavior. I did not solve the problem yet, but I have some findings. I will share with you so maybe you can develop on this and find a solutions.

I observed that in general the JS code called by the applicationDidEnterBackground (as well as the one called by applicationWillResignActive) is executed.

To test this, I set up a counter global to all my JS code, I increment it before going in BG and I check its state while in background (to check it I used a dirty workaround where I basically create a new file called cntr_#{counter value}), so I assume that the JS function is called (since the counter is incremented).

However, before incrementing the counter, my JS function also sends a XMPP message. When I sniff the network traffic, I see that the XMPP message is sent immediately after the app is resumed. Now there are two possibilities: either the transition to BG has not the possibility of creating a XMPP connection (which I think is not plausible), either the XMPP function happens asynchronously and its execution is postponed.

**Update.**

I discovered that the JS library I was using for XMPP is actually asynchronous and that calling a flush over its queue solved the issue of the missing XMPP messages. Hope this can help you too.